# Play video in VLC in CLI Linux

Tags: linux, vlc, orange-pi

I'm trying to play video in VLC in CLI Armbian on OrangePi. In a fresh install of Armbian, I installed VLC and downloaded a sample video. When I play video

```
vlc video.mp4
```

everything seems working correctly:

[image: correct video]

But when I create file run.sh with

```
vlc video.mp4
```

and then run it

```
./run.sh
```

the video is not playing correctly:

[image: bad video]

What am I doing wrong with playing the video from run.sh script?

Comment: this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185081/force-vlc-to-load-ui-on-raspberry-booted-to-cli?rq=1) seems like a similar problem, and the guy also added an answer

Comment: the video is playing correctly but using the ASCII output. You need to set up `x11` forwarding (`ssh -X ...`)  and set the proper display as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636268/play-a-video-with-vlc-in-x11-from-remote-terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks dafnahaktana, with your reply after some googling I found a solution

```
xinit -- /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper video.mp4
```